# In R or excel, can I add a column of x amount of each number counting up

Tags: r, excel, csv, formula

Basically I have a dataset extracted from photos. Each photo has 25 data points but there is no indication which photo each point is from. I would like to add a column where I have 25 x 1's, 25 x 2's, 25 x 3's etc for around 2500 photos so I can distinguish individual images. Any suggestions? TIA

[**Example of table**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHCTm.png)

Comment: `df$photo_id <- rep(1:2500, each = 25)` where `df` is your dataframe and 2500 is the number of photos. You need to get the total number of photos right else it will error. Also hopefully the rows are in the right order to do something like this

Comment: You could try something along these lines: `df$ID <- 1 + (1:nrow(df) - 1) %/% 25` with `df` being your data.frame.

Comment: In excel, you could have a formula like `=FLOOR((ROW(A13)-ROW($A$13))/25,0)+1` where the $A$13 is anchored to your first row you want to number